# Why are some error messages in executable binary

Tags: windows, executable

Answering another question about how const string data was stored in an executable a question occured: Why are run time error messages  stored in the executable rather than generated by the OS?

`!This program cannot be run in DOS mode.`
Seems reasonable, DOS can't be expected to detect a newer Windows app and generate an appropriate error message. Some others about stack frame corrupted might also occur when your program is in a state where it can't reliably communicate with an OS function

But some make no sense:
`- Attempt to use MSIL code from this assembly during native code initialization...etc..`
If I was trying to call a .Net assembly (which I don't - this is pure C++ code) surely the .Net or OS runtime could manage to generate the error message itself.

And the file system error messages are also in the exe. Surely I want these errors to be generated by the OS at run time - if the app is being run on a non-english version of Windows don't I want system errors to reflect that language rather than the one I used to compile it?

Just a Friday afternoon sort of question but there doesn't seem to be anything about it on [Raymond Chen's site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/)

Comment: This question is not about Windows in general, it is about the tool-chain used to compile/link. Maybe add a VS related tag if you are using Visual Studio...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples I know of are stubs that are placed specifically because there isn't a good way for the OS or some runtime to produce the error.  Also, they are fundamental problems with the implementation, not the types of errors a user should ever see.

The DOS one is a perfect example.  There's no way for DOS to recognize a Windows program and produce a reasonable error, so the stub code is included in Windows programs.

Your MSIL one is very similar.  How can the runtime produce this error if the runtime isn't actually loaded (because the program is still initializing)?

Another example I can think of are "Pure virtual function called" in C++ programs.  The abstract base class vtables are filled with stubs that emit this message.  I suppose they *could* be stubs that make an OS call to produce the same message, but that seems like overkill for something that's never supposed to happen.

There's a similar problem if you try to call into the floating point library from a native C or C++ program that isn't actually linked against the floating point library.  This is essentially a floating-point implementation detail of the language runtime library (in cooperation with the compiler and the linker).  It's not an OS-level issue (in the sense that something like "file not found" is).

Answer (score 0):

It's so you can globalise your application.

E.g
Ivan can have the error messages in Russian even though it's running on a French OS.

Comment: But while I can translate my message strings I can't change the compiler supplied ones. So if I use an app written by a Russian I would get "file not found" in Russian (or possibly not if it needs a cyrilic font)

Comment: Actually I seem to remember from MFC days you could package a language specific runtime with the app, but I think this was only for MFC's system string table

Comment: You could provide your own I seem to remember, even multiple languages.I remember looking at it Delphi compiled win32 apps many moons `ago. Development never happened, and I've never been near a need to do it since.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is code pulled in by the CRT, try compiling a test application that does not link with the [default libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1tbxcxh%28v=vs.100%29) and use mainCRTstartup as the entry point, then the only string should be the error message in the DOS stub.